# Using Async in Angular Services

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

So I have two services and one component below.

This is ros.service.ts, it establishes the connection with my server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RosService {

  // Creates object with the ROS library
  // @ts-ignore <= Makes ts happy, wont error
  ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      // Set listen URL for ROS communication
      url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
  });

  initialize() {
      let data;
      // Listens for error from ROS and logs it
      this.ros.on('error', function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      });

      // Find out exactly when we made a connection.
      this.ros.on('connection', function() {
          console.log('Connection made!');
      });
      // Logs when connection is closed
      this.ros.on('close', function() {
          console.log('Connection closed.');
      });
  }
}

// Data is gotten through subscription from each node service
// this.driveControlService.getDriveControlData().subscribe(msg => {
//   this.data = msg;
//   console.log(msg);
// });
// }
```

Next, this is a service calling from a subset of the server (or node for those experienced with ROS)
ms5837.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import '../../assets/roslib.js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Ms5837Service {
  // Creates object with the ROS library
  // @ts-ignore <= Makes ts happy, wont error
  ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
    // Set listen URL for ROS communication
    url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
  });
  // Define subject to hold data values
  ms5837: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  // Initializer to be called every time BMP280 is going to be used
  initialize() {
    // Get Data from ROS bmp280 Topic
    // @ts-ignore
    const ms5837Listener = new ROSLIB.Topic({
      ros: this.ros,
      name: '/rov/ms5837',
      messageType: 'ms5837/ms5837_data'
    });

    // Subscribe to bmpListener
    ms5837Listener.subscribe((message) => {
      console.log('Recieved Message on ' + ms5837Listener.name + ' : ' + message);
      // console.log(message);
      this.ms5837.next(message);
    });
  }
  // Define data getter
  getData(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.ms5837) {
      return this.ms5837.asObservable();
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, I'm trying to get the data in this component and assign it to data for use in a graph.
telemetrydata.component.ts

```
import {OnInit, Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Ms5837Service } from '../../../services/ms5837.service';
import { Ms5837Data } from '../../../services/data-models/ms5837.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-depth-chart',
  templateUrl: './depth-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./depth-chart.component.css']
})
export class DepthChartComponent implements OnInit {
    exteriorAltitude = [0];
    seconds = [0];
    name = 'Depth Chart';
    type = 'line';
    data = {
        labels: this.seconds,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Depth',
            data: this.exteriorAltitude,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0,188,212, .3)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#00bcd4'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
            }]
    };
    options = {
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };
    constructor(private ms5837Service: Ms5837Service) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.ms5837Service.initialize();
        this.ms5837Service.getData().subscribe((msg: Ms5837Data) => {
            if (msg !== undefined) {
              console.log(msg);
              this.exteriorAltitude.push(msg.altitudeM);
              console.log(this.exteriorAltitude);
              this.seconds.push(msg.header.stamp.secs);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Currently, it takes a little bit to establish a connection with the server, so the first value passed through the observable to telemetrydata.component.ts is undefined, which crashes angular. I tried playing around with async and promise but quite frankely I'm not skilled enough with rxjs yet to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first value is not undefined. It's 1: the initial value of the BehaviorSubect. The second one, even if it's undefined, shouldn't make anything fail, since you do nothing if msg is undefined. Please explain what actually happens, and post all the relevant logs and error messages and stack traces. Also, I don't see how the first class is relevant, since it isn't used anywhere.

Comment: @JBNizet the first service is required to establish the connection. I forgot to add that it's called in my App Module onInit. I will add logs shortly.

Comment: I don't know anything about ROS, bt I doubt that it's needed. All it does is the same thin as the second one, plus registering callbacks to be notified when the connection is established or closed or when there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem magically fixed itself (?) So problem solved I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this and hope that my answer is helpful.

It looks like you don't need both services to make this work... Am I wrong? I don't see your constructor for your second service but I don't see where you are using the first service.  That say I am only going to look at the second service and the component.

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import '../../assets/roslib.js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Ms5837Service {
  ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
    // Set listen URL for ROS communication
    url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
  });

  // Here I am just returning the observable from ROS

  getData(): Observable<Any> {
    return new ROSLIB.Topic({
          ros: this.ros,
          name: '/rov/ms5837',
          messageType: 'ms5837/ms5837_data'
        });
  }
}
```

Component

```
import {OnInit, Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Ms5837Service } from '../../../services/ms5837.service';
import { Ms5837Data } from '../../../services/data-models/ms5837.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-depth-chart',
  templateUrl: './depth-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./depth-chart.component.css']
})
export class DepthChartComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    // adding a subscsription here
    rosData: Subscription;

    exteriorAltitude = [0];
    seconds = [0];
    name = 'Depth Chart';
    type = 'line';
    data = {
        labels: this.seconds,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Depth',
            data: this.exteriorAltitude,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0,188,212, .3)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#00bcd4'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
            }]
    };
    options = {
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };
    constructor(private ms5837Service: Ms5837Service) {}
    ngOnInit() {

        // this should fire every time the subscription receives a notice
        this.rosData = this.ms5837Service.getData().subscribe((msg: Ms5837Data) => {
            if (msg !== undefined) {
              console.log(msg);
              this.exteriorAltitude.push(msg.altitudeM);
              console.log(this.exteriorAltitude);
              this.seconds.push(msg.header.stamp.secs);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.rosData.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```